# I am trying to develop an activity in which user can record and save there audio in the internal storage

Tags: java, android, voice-recording

I am trying to develop an activity in which I can record my audio until I touch my button at the movement button is been released the file should be saved in the storage. The file gets created and been saved inside the folder but when I click the button as a normal, error occurs. I have tried my level best to do but every time I get an error. getting an error that says

java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)

Please help me so that I can complete my project.

```
     private void audiorecordermethod(){
   if(checkPermission()){
       capturebutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                   validateMicAvailability();
                   AudioSavePathInDevice =
                           Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Alpha/Voice/Send/" ;
                   File audiodir = new File(AudioSavePathInDevice);
                   if (!audiodir.exists()){
                       audiodir.mkdirs();
                   }
                   String filepath = audiodir + "/"+ CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + ".3gp";
                   MediaRecorderReady(filepath);

                   try {
                       mediaRecorder.prepare();
                       mediaRecorder.start();
                   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

                   return true;
               }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                      mediaRecorder.stop();
                      mediaRecorder.release();

                   return true;
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
   }else{
       requestPermission();
   }
}

public void MediaRecorderReady(String filepath){
    mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filepath);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);

}

public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( string );
    int i = 0 ;
    while(i < string ) {
        stringBuilder.append(RandomAudioFileName.
                charAt(random.nextInt(RandomAudioFileName.length())));

        i++ ;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

private void requestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(personalChat.this, new
            String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, RequestPermissionCode);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestPermissionCode:
            if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {
                    Toast.makeText(personalChat.this, "Permission Granted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(personalChat.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            RECORD_AUDIO);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Logcat

```
 10-24 15:50:51.762 9687-9687/com.nanb.alpha E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nanb.alpha, PID: 9687
java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
    at com.nanb.alpha.personalChat$7.onTouch(personalChat.java:312)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8476)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2402)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1752)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2785)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2363)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8677)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4144)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4010)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3565)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3618)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3592)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3758)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3565)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3618)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3584)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3592)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3565)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5828)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5802)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5773)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5918)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Comment: add full exception log in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you try to stop the MediaRecorder before it is prepared, a quick solution could be this:

```
try{
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.release();
}catch (Exception e){
}
```

Check the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#stop%28%29):

> Note that a RuntimeException is intentionally thrown to the
>   application, if no valid audio/video data has been received when
>   stop() is called. This happens if stop() is called immediately after
>   start(). The failure lets the application take action accordingly to
>   clean up the output file (delete the output file, for instance), since
>   the output file is not properly constructed when this happens.